# 'str' object is not callable during running the code

Tags: python-3.x

During running the code below I've got the error message:

> "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

As I understood the problem occured when I tried to call through print the object which is 'str' and not callable (unlike to functions). When I modified the line print(text()) to print(text) the code works well. So, as a pythons begginer, I'm curious, why those happened, because I'm calling function, which at the same time return str.?

```
    def decor(func):
        x = "="
        return x + func() + x
    @decor
    def text():
        return "test"
    print(text())
```

I expect that result will be =test=. From my point of view, I'm call the function `text()` which return str value "test". Function `text()` is decorated one, so after calling `text()` due the concatenation of strings from decorator and decorated one I have to see output: `=test=`, but the actual output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(text())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'
```

Answer (score 2):

return of decorator function should be a callable. So in this case return should be a function.

Following will work

```
def decor(func):
    def wrapfunc():
        x = "="
        return x + func() + x

    return wrapfunc

@decor
def text():
    return "test"

print(text())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your decorator function isn't right. You need to make it have a [`wrapper`](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#simple-decorators) inside:

```
def decor(func):
    def wrapper():
        x = "="
        return x + func() + x
    return wrapper

@decor
def text():
    return "test"

text()
'=test='
```